# how to access data from the nested Master/Detail grid from Ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, nested, ag-grid

I'm using a nested master/Detail grid. For the first level grid, I can use getRowId to assign a custom ID to the child, But not on the second level if I use getRowId grid functionality is broken and throws a warning like getRowId duplicate node. My nested grid looks like the following [1- level] Master -> child (  [2 level] Master  -> child ).

I need to access the second-level child node in the master grid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.